# Apple Watch pairing prompts for old Apple ID password

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password, messages, apple-watch

When I paired my Apple Watch with my iPhone it asked for me to login to my Apple ID.

[image: first Apple ID login prompt]

Later while configuring Messages on the watch it asks for my password again.

[image: second Apple ID login prompt for old Apple ID]

However, the ***Apple ID in each is different***, none of my current or previous Apple ID passwords succeeds at this prompt, and I am forced to hit Cancel to proceed.

Several months ago I changed my Apple ID from `cory@coryklein.com` to `coryfklein@gmail.com` and I assume Apple has retained the older ID somewhere in association with Messages.

Messages on my MacBook is using the correct ID.

[image: messages app configuration on computer]

My iPhone is using the correct ID as well.

[image: apple id on iPhone]

Unfortunately, this appears to be causing the Messages app on the Watch not to sync with my phone. I can't send or receive messages on my Watch.

Has anybody else encountered this and succeeded in resolving it?

I don't have Two-Factor authentication enabled on my Apple ID, but I have started the process and am waiting the mandatory 3-day period for it to activate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login with your Apple ID at Settings > Messages > Send & Receive > Apple ID